# setting arguments in bash(trying to run script and no output)

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have script that needs to check if the file is exists and additionally set up arguments. From user side user runs a script and checks if the file exists ./xxx.sh -f folder/file and then prints out the if the device "is provosional or unpprovasision" I wrote the code but there is no output or i'm not even able to check if the file exists.

````
```

Help() {
#Display help
        echo " Tool "
        helpText
}

helpText() {
        echo
        echo "Syntax: [-p|u]"
        echo "options"
        echo "  runscript put location of file to see if it exists if device exists"
        echo " p        PROVISION DEVICE"
        echo " u        UNPROVISION DEVICE"
        echo
}
 ## Validations

    # Does the file exist
   # if [[ ! -f $device_file ]]; then
    #    echo "Error: The file $device_file does not exist."
     #   exit 1
   # fi

main() {


do_provision=0   # initialize variables
do_unprovision=0
device_file=””


  while getopts "d:uph?" option; do
          case $option in

           d)
               device_file=$OPTARG
               ;;
           u)
               do_unprovision=1
               echo "unprov"
               ;;
           p)
               do_provision=1
               ;;

           h)
                Help
                exit;;

           \?)  echo "Error: Invalid option"
                exit;;
   esac
  done


}`enter code here`

```
````

Comment: You already have getopts set up here. What's the real question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @tjm3772  so when i run the script nothing happens it doesn't not get any  output. for example i want to check if the file exist so i run script ./xxx.sh folder/file it doesn't give me anything and additionally i don't think i set up get up correct way!

Comment: [Edit] the question to show exactly how you're testing and what results you get _as part of the question text_. Comments are helpful, but they don't count towards whether a question is complete enough to be considered on-topic or not.

Comment: Also, to better comply with [mre] rules, try to shorten your program as much as possible while making sure it still has the problem described when run without changes. (For example, `helpText` can just be `echo "Would show help text here"` if the problem isn't actually specific to showing that text).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing quite a few things wrong in the script here.

1. getopts won't work in a function like that
2. you're not executing the main function in your script
3. where you're trying to do the file check is before you aim to get the device file option
4. you haven't gotten a check to see if the variable has anything in it before checking for a file

Here is a working version of your script with the errors corrected. If you only want the device file checked when running the -d option then you need to put those if statements in a function and change the case part.

```
#!/bin/bash

function Help() {
    #Display help
    echo " Tool "
    helpText
}

function helpText() {
    echo "Syntax: [-p|u]"
    echo "options"
    echo "  runscript put location of file to see if it exists if device exists"
    echo " p        PROVISION DEVICE"
    echo " u        UNPROVISION DEVICE"
}


# initialize variables
do_provision=0
do_unprovision=0
device_file=""

while getopts "d:uph?" option; do
    case "${option}" in
       d)
           device_file=$OPTARG
        ;;
       u)
           do_unprovision=1
           echo "unprov"
        ;;
       p)
           do_provision=1
        ;;
       h)
            Help
            exit
        ;;
       *)
            echo "Error: Invalid option"
            exit
        ;;
    esac
done

## Validations
# Does the file exist
if [ -z $device_file ]; then
    echo "Error: No file provided. Use -d option"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Checking device file '$device_file'"
if [ ! -f $device_file ]; then
    echo "Error: The file $device_file does not exist."
    exit 2
fi
```